# Next.js not receiving cookie from Django

Tags: django, authentication, cookies, next.js

I am messing around with Next.js and regular Django to do some testing, study etc.

I am trying to make a basic authentication system that simply takes the email and password, send to the Django server and it simply returns a cookie with the user id.

When I login with valid credentials, the server returns an "OK" (as it is supposed to do), however I don't get any of the cookies I'm supposed to have (not even the default csrf token from Django).

(sample data for design testing)

[image]

Using Django 4.0.6 and Next.js 12.3.1

Login route on Django

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(req):
    body = json.loads(req.body.decode("utf-8"))

    res = None

    if (User.objects.filter(email=body["email"])):
        user = User.objects.get(email=body["email"])

        if (user.password == body["password"]):
            res = JsonResponse({"success": True})
            res.status_code = 200

            res.set_cookie("AuthToken", json.dumps(
                {"id": user.id}),
                max_age=60 * 60 * 24,
                httponly=False,
                samesite="strict",
            )
        else:
            res = JsonResponse({"success": False})
            res.status_code = 401

    else:
        res = JsonResponse({"success": False})
        res.status_code = 404

    res.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    print(res.cookies)
    return res
```

My login page on Next

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { CONFIG } from "../../../DESIGN_CONFIG";

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();

  async function logIn(e: FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password });

    console.log(body);

    console.log(process.env.API_URL);

    const res = await fetch(process.env.API_URL + "login/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: body,
    });

    console.log(res);

    if (res.status === 200) {
      router.push("/");
    }
  }

  return (
    <Background>
      <LoginForm onSubmit={logIn}>
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          id="password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        <button type="submit">Log In</button>

        <span>
          Or{" "}
          <Link href="/user/sign-up">
            <a>sign-up</a>
          </Link>
        </span>
      </LoginForm>
    </Background>
  );
}


// This way down just got the styled-components for background and login form
```

Prints in the console of the body and the res (and the api route):

[image]

I'm using no middleware on Next nor Django and haven't changed anything in the _app.js.

I tried using invalid credentials and got the expected behavior.

I tried using Postman and it gets the cookies.

[image]

I tried making a simpler cookie.

```
res.set_cookie("AuthToken", user.id)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting it the not complicated way?: `res.set_cookie('id', user.id)`

Comment: @Nealium yep, no success though, same result :(

Comment: I was thinking **not** using AuthToken as the key too :-) sounds important and prob shouldn’t overwrite. But bummer! :(